# java: cannot access com.google.auth.Credentials class file for com.google.auth.Credentials not found

Tags: java, firebase, gradle, firebase-admin

I'm using the firebase Admin SDK and im getting this error at runtime:

```
Error:(22, 36) java: cannot access com.google.auth.Credentials
class file for com.google.auth.Credentials not found
```

This is the constructor that is throwing the error

```
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Database{

private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;

Database(){

    InputStream serviceAccount = Database.class.getResourceAsStream("reading-incentive-firebase-adminsdk-n556s-1b742e4b58.json");

    FirebaseOptions options;
    try {
        options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredentials( GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                .setDatabaseUrl("https://reading-incentive.firebaseio.com")
                .build();
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error loading database");
    }

    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

}

}
```

this is line 22

> .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))

I'm using the java sdk 1.8 in IntelliJ along with gradle. I've read other posts and read that using sdk 1.8 over 1.7 throws the error but I can't find a solution. Here is my build.gradle file...

```
group 'src'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.5.0'
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hi Andrew, what is the environment you are running this? is it google app engine?

Comment: I'm not using google app engine, I'm building a desktop app on wiondows with JavaFX.

Comment: I posted an answer. let me know whether it worked or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue a while back when I was trying to do the firebase integration in our app engine project. This is caused by a some sort of transient dependency you are having in your application within google libraries.

Please try these things,

if you are using lower version of appengine-api upgrade it to `appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.64.jar` or higher.

then check your dependencies. if you are using either one of these,

```
google-oauth-client-1.22.0.jar
google-oauth-client-appengine-1.22.0.jar
google-oauth-client-servlet-1.22.0.jar
```

that could be the conflict. try removing them (you might not need them). hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry for taking a while to respond, I don't have any of those dependencies in my app. I noticed that 'google-oauth-client-1.25.0' is in the external libraies folder but nowhere in my local source or in my gradle file.

Comment: so remove it man, as long as you can refer it through your project It might cause a conflict.

Comment: awesome. glad I could help..!