# class file for com.google.auth.Credentials not found

Tags: java, firebase, maven, javafx, firebase-admin

I can't use GoogleCredentials in Firebaseoptions. I got the following error when I export with Maven:

```
  class file for com.google.auth.Credentials not found

 FirebaseOptions options = FirebaseOptions.builder()

                    .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                    // Your Database URL can be found in your firebase console -> your project
                    .setDatabaseUrl("https://health-45311.firebaseio.com/")
                    .build();
```

In Intellij I cant import the package, but when I export with Maven nothing works.

My pom.xml

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>15.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>15.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.oauth-client/google-oauth-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.31.2</version>
        </dependency>




    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that **"firebase-admin"** dependency have another version of the **"google-oauth-client"**. Try to exclude from the pom

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
        <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
                <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

A good way to check this kind of things is run **mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose** in the console.

**Edit - post response**

I found that there was a question similar in the past. [Here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52671448/java-cannot-access-com-google-auth-credentials-class-file-for-com-google-auth-c)