# Java Cannot access com.google.auth.Credentials

Tags: java, firebase, maven, javafx

I am developing a simple JavaFx application for a client using Firebase.

This application worked perfectly without JavaFx, however I had to re-create this project to get JavaFx working with it (simply adding dependencies didn't work).

I know this question is a possible duplicate, but I have tried almost all methods suggested before. (linked the ones I tried below)

When using GoogleCredentials, the application throws this error:

```
java: cannot access com.google.auth.Credentials
  class file for com.google.auth.Credentials not found
```

This is the class that has the method: (See the private constructor)

```
public class DataManage {
    private FirebaseOptions options;
    private Firestore firestore;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    public static DataManage getInstance() {
        return Holder.INSTANCE;
    }

    public void initApp() {
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
    }

    public UserRecord getUserInfo(String email) {
        try {
            return mAuth.getUserByEmail(email);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void getUserDataFromDate(String email, Date date) {
        try {
            //Todo add stuff later
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /// I call the GoogleCredentials.fromStream() method here
    private DataManage() {
        try {
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("service-account.json");

            options = FirebaseOptions.builder()
                    .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(inputStream))
                    .setDatabaseUrl("https://attendance-349db.firebaseio.com/")
                    .build();

            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

            firestore = FirestoreClient.getFirestore();
            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static class Holder {
        private static final DataManage INSTANCE = new DataManage();
    }
}
```

This is my maven dependency file: (only including the dependencies and part of build to avoid cluttering)

Dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
                    <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>17-ea+11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>17-ea+11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Build:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.indo.attendanceserver/com.indo.attendanceserver.Main</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

My modules:

```
module com.indo.attendanceserver {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires firebase.admin;
    requires google.cloud.firestore;
    requires com.google.auth.oauth2;


    opens com.indo.attendanceserver to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.indo.attendanceserver;
    exports com.indo.attendanceserver.scenes.intro;
    opens com.indo.attendanceserver.scenes.intro to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.indo.attendanceserver.scenes.user;
    opens com.indo.attendanceserver.scenes.user to javafx.fxml;
}
```

Here are the links to suggestions that I've tried but didn't work:

[No app-engine files in my project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52671448/java-cannot-access-com-google-auth-credentials-class-file-for-com-google-auth-c).

[Excluding didn't help, tried without excluding too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65468514/class-file-for-com-google-auth-credentials-not-found)

[Latest version for both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69543340/javafx-intellij-error-java-cannot-access-com-google-auth-credentials-class)

[No updates from this person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67925943/java-cannot-access-com-google-auth-credentials-class-file-for-com-google-auth-c)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to fix this issue.

All I had to do was add

```
requires com.google.auth;
```

to my `module-info.java` file.

The final file looks something like this:

```
module com.indo.attendanceserver {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires firebase.admin;
    requires google.cloud.firestore;
    requires com.google.auth.oauth2;
    requires com.google.auth;



    opens com.indo.attendanceserver to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.indo.attendanceserver;
    exports com.indo.attendanceserver.scenes.intro;
    opens com.indo.attendanceserver.scenes.intro to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.indo.attendanceserver.scenes.user;
    opens com.indo.attendanceserver.scenes.user to javafx.fxml;
}
```

I hope this helps anyone who is looking for an answer.